# Invalid OpCode while deploying "HelloWorld"

Tags: ganache, opcode

I'm receiving the following error message trying to deploy a very simple contract to Ganache. How can I resolve this?

**Contract**:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;  // ^0.4.24; 

contract HelloWorld {
    string private helloMessage = "Hello world";

    function getHelloMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
        return helloMessage;
    }
}
```

**Error Message following "truffle deploy --reset" command:**

```
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\HelloWorld.sol
> Compilation warnings encountered:

    Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> project:/contracts/HelloWorld.sol


> Artifacts written to C:\Users\markp\workspace\firstProject_Source\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.21+commit.d9974bed.Emscripten.clang


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


2_contracts_migration.js
========================

   Deploying 'HelloWorld'
   ----------------------
 *** Deployment Failed ***

"HelloWorld" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.
```

**Error: Deployment Failed**

```
"HelloWorld" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

 at C:\Users\markp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:330:1  
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Node v18.18.2
PS C:\Users\markp\workspace\firstProject_Source>
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `2_contracts_migration.js` since this is where the issue seems to be? The contract code itself is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The 0x5f PUSH0 opcode was added with the Shanghai upgrade, and was supported from solc version ^0.8.20.

Perhaps your local ganache chain is running on an older EVM version, hence the conflict with your 0.8.21 compiler version.

Try compiling with 0.8.19, or looking at your ganache settings.